# js running line which it is not suppose to in an if in a for

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the number of adjacent (w/ corners) that have a certain class but returns error.

Html is table with empty tbody.

Css:

```
table{
   border-collapse:collapse;
   background-color:black;
}
td{
   width:47.5px;
   height47.5px;
   padding:0px;
   border:2.5px solid gray;
}
td.live{
   background-color:white;
}
```

**js:**

```
            const size={
                x:5,
                y:5
            };
            var matrix=[];
            for(var i=[0, 0], rows=[]; i[0]<size.y; i[0]++){
                rows.push(document.createElement("tr"));
                document.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(rows[i[0]]);
                matrix.push([]);
                for(i[1]=0; i[1]<size.x; i[1]++){
                    matrix[i[0]][i[1]]=document.createElement("td");
                    matrix[i[0]][i[1]].setAttribute("x", i[1]);
                    matrix[i[0]][i[1]].setAttribute("y", i[0])
                    rows[i[0]].appendChild(matrix[i[0]][i[1]]);
                }
            }
            for(var i=[0,0]; i[0]<matrix.length; i[0]++){
                for(i[1]=0; i[1]<matrix[0].length; i[1]++){
                    matrix[i[0]][i[1]].onclick=function(){
                        this.classList.toggle("live");
                    }
                }
            }
            var interval=setInterval(loop(), 500);
            function loop(){
                for(var i=[0,0]; i[0]<matrix.length; i[0]++){
                    for(i[1]=0; i[1]<matrix[0].length; i[1]++){
                        const x=Number(matrix[i[0]][i[1]].getAttribute("x"));
                        const y=Number(matrix[i[0]][i[1]].getAttribute("y"));
                        var liveNeighbors=0;
                        if(x!=size.x){
                            if(document.querySelector('td[x="'+(x+1)+'"]').classList.contains("live")){
                                liveNeighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(y!=size.y){
                            if(document.querySelector('td[y="'+(y+1)+'"]').classList.contains("live")){
                                liveNeighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(x!=0){
                            if(document.querySelector('td[x="'+(x-1)+'"]').classList.contains("live")){
                                liveNeighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(y!=0){
                            if(document.querySelector('td[y="'+(y-1)+'"]').classList.contains("live")){
                                liveNeighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(!(matrix[i[0]][i[1]].classList.contains("live"))&&liveNeighbors==3){
                            matrix[i[0]][i[1]].classList.add("live");
                        }
                        if(matrix[i[0]][i[1]].classList.contains("live")&&(liveNeighbors!=2||liveNeighbors!=3)){
                            matrix[i[0]][i[1]].classList.remove("live");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the error:

*
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
at loop
*

I think it is running code in the if loops when it should not.

Thanks in advance! (:

Comment: it's not getting one unique element with that query selector check if you have multiple matches then get them assigned properly  `document.querySelector('td[y="'+(y+1)+'"]')[i].classList`

Comment: The _document.querySelecotor()_ method only returns 1 element, the _document.querySelectorAll()_ method does.

Comment: Try to add a full snippet with HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this over-complicated with your matrix array when a table itself is a matrix.

A table element has a `rows` property that returns collection of it's rows than can be indexed. Table also has  method [insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)

A table row has a `cells` property that can also be indexed and it has a method [insertCell()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

Following is a bit rough and not bug free with regard to the live counts but should give you a good idea how to do this without ever needing to use `querySelector()` and how to iterate all the rows and cells

```js
const size = { x: 5, y:5};
const table = document.querySelector('table');

buildRows()
setInterval(loop, 2000);



function getLiveCount(cell){
   const {x, y} = cell.dataset;
   const rows = table.rows;
   const left = rows[y].cells[x-1],
         right = rows[y].cells[x+1],
         above = rows[y-1] && rows[y-1].cells[x],
         below = rows[y+1] && rows[y+1].cells[x];
   return [left, right, above, below].filter(cell=>cell)
          .reduce((a, currCell)=> a + currCell.matches('.live'),0)      
}

function loop(){ 
   [...table.rows].forEach((row, i)=> {    
      [...row.cells].forEach(cell=> cell.textContent = getLiveCount(cell))      
   });
}

function buildRow(y) {
   const row = table.insertRow();
   for(let i=0; i <size.x; i++){
      const cell = row.insertCell();
      Object.assign(cell.dataset, {x:i, y});
      cell.addEventListener('click',cellClick);      
   }  
}

function buildRows(){
   for(let i =0; i< size.y; i++){
       buildRow(i)
   }
}


function cellClick(event){
   this.classList.toggle('live')
   console.log('x:', this.dataset.x, ' y:', this.dataset.y)
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

td.live {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```